# Swift - Localizable file working properly in all except one iPad device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently working on an Xcode project that has several different targets, each one with their own strings defined for specific parts of the app. That is why we are using different string files, which we call depending on the target we are running.

I came across a strange problem which I still could not find a way to reproduce. One of the devices of a client is showing the name of the key instead of showing the string defined for that target or the default string in the file "default.string". The problem is that all other test devices (simulator and physical devices) we used show the strings correctly. The device that is not showing strings properly (and just showing the key) is an iPad 7th Generation, with iPadOS 14.

I am using the following code to show the string on the view (note that I am using "section2HomeTitle" as an example here):

```
FactoryView.sectionHeaderView(with: Strings.localizedString(forKey: Strings.LocalizedStringKey.section2HomeTitle), icon: Constants.Config.useIconSectionsHomeTitle ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imbatibles"): nil )
```

The key section2HomeTitle is defined in a file for Constants the following way:

```
struct Strings {
struct LocalizedStringKey {
    static let section2HomeTitle = "section2HomeTitle"
}}
```

Also in the Constants file, I have the following function defined, which looks for the definition of key "section2HomeTitle" in the localized files:

```
static func localizedString(forKey key: String) -> String {
    var result = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: Constants.Config.store)
    if result == key {
        result = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: "default")
    }
    return result
}
```

That function looks for the current target's definition for that particular key using `Constants.Config.store`. If it does not find the key in that target's file, it will look for it in the `default` file.

In this case I am dealing with Target store "xyz", and therefore I define its keys in file **xyz.string** which has Localization language set to Spanish and Target Membership set to "xyz" target. The key is defined in that file with the following string:

```
"section2HomeTitle" = "REBAJAS";
```

In case the file is not found, I have the "default" file defined as **default.string** which has Localization language set to Spanish and Target Membershipt set to "xyz" target and all other targets in the project. The key definition here is:

```
"section2HomeTitle" = "Ofertas";
```

As I mentioned before, the output shows up as "REBAJAS" in all devices we tested for that target, except in that one iPad 7th Gen from the client, where it shows:`section2HomeTitle`

My questions are:

- Why is this key showing up correctly in all devices we test it, except on the client's iPad 7th Gen
- What can I do to correct this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: "iPadOS 14": Which version exactly (just in case). Also in `Settings.app/General/Languages & Regions`, what are the settings?

Comment: @Larme, thank you for your prompt reply. I will try to find out from the client which version exactly (they are on holiday today, so it will be tomorrow).
By `Settings.app/General/Languages & Regions` you mean the settings for that particular app on the iPad? Or is it in Xcode?
If it is the settings in iPad, would I access it through Config -> App name -> Language ?

Comment: In the iPad that's having the issue. Might be a strange combination of languages settings. In the iPad, there is a `Settings.app`, that's where I meant.

Comment: Ok, let me get back to you on that. Tomorrow the client goes back to work.
So far what I know is that under Settings > General > Language & Region, the settings are:
Language: English.
Preferred Language Order:
English,
Español (Spanish).
Region: Mexico.
Calendar: Gregorian.
Temperature Unit: ºC.
By the way, even if there were a strange combination of language settings, shouldn't the code still grab the default?

Comment: Depending on how it's configured, it should have a default language indeed. But then try to reproduce the same languages settings in your device to see the issue.

Comment: Yes, I tried to reproduce in my device (physical iPhone, not iPad) and in the simulators, without being able to see the issue the client is having.
As soon as I have the other info on the settings, I will post back.